# Tensorflow embeddings InvalidArgumentError: indices[18,16] = 11905 is not in [0, 11905) [[node sequential_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, word2vec, embedding, word-embedding

I am using TF 2.2.0 and trying to create a Word2Vec CNN text classification model. But however I tried there has been always an issue with the model or embedding layers. I could not found clear solutions in the internet so decided to ask it.

```
import multiprocessing
modelW2V = gensim.models.Word2Vec(filtered_stopwords_list, size= 100, min_count = 5, window = 5, sg=0, iter = 10, workers= multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1)
model_save_location = "3000tweets_notbinary"
modelW2V.wv.save_word2vec_format(model_save_location)

word2vec = {}
with open('3000tweets_notbinary', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split()
        word = values[0]
        vec = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
        word2vec[word] = vec

num_words = len(list(tokenizer.word_index))

embedding_matrix = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (num_words, 100))
for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    if i < num_words:
        embedding_vector = word2vec.get(word)
        if embedding_vector is not None:
          embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
        else:
          embedding_matrix[i] = np.zeros((100,))
```

I have created my word2vec weights by the code above and then converted it to embedding_matrix as I followed on many tutorials. But since there are a lot of words seen by word2vec but not available in embeddings, if there is no embedding I assign 0 vector. And then fed data and this embedding to tf sequential model.

```
seq_leng = max_tokens
vocab_size = num_words
embedding_dim = 100
filter_sizes = [3, 4, 5]
num_filters = 512
drop = 0.5
epochs = 5
batch_size = 32

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                                    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim= vocab_size,
                                                              output_dim= embedding_dim,
                                                              weights = [embedding_matrix],
                                                              input_length= max_tokens,
                                                              trainable= False),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(num_filters, 7, activation= "relu", padding= "same"),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(2),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(num_filters, 7, activation= "relu", padding= "same"),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation= "relu", kernel_regularizer= tf.keras.regularizers.l2(1e-4)),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation= "softmax")
])

model.compile(loss= "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate= 0.001, epsilon= 1e-06),
              metrics= ["accuracy", tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(x_train_pad, y_train2, batch_size= 60, epochs= epochs, shuffle= True, verbose= 1)
```

But when I run this code, tensorflow gives me the following error in any random time of the training process. But I could not find any solution to it. I have tried adding + 1 to vocab_size but when I do that I get size mismatch error which does not let me even compile my model. Can anyone please help me?

```
InvalidArgumentError:  indices[18,16] = 11905 is not in [0, 11905)
     [[node sequential_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-26-ef1b16cf85bf>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1533]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup/991 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: Let me clarify it, do you need to use embeddings for some words only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this solution. I was adding a new dimension to vocab_size by doing it vocab_size + 1 as suggested by others. However, since sizes of layer dimensions and embedding matrix don't match I got this issue in my hands. I added a zero vector at the end of my embedding matrix which solved the issue.

Comment: In my example there are around 40k different words, and then I create word2vec by enumerating those words (i get dict of word:index), and in that case I do not get any errors. But then I have enriched that dict with more than 10000 new key:values (words that are not in the vocab) and then I started getting this error. Do you know what can be the probelm?

Comment: @taga I believe that is too late for an answer but. In my experience adding more dimensions solved the issue for many case. But this can also create issues related to your word indices. I don't yet know a correct approach for additions above 2 let me say.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Approach:
model = Sequential()
embeddings = Embedding(20, 31, input_length=win_size)

Right Approach:
model = Sequential()
embeddings = Embedding(21, 31, input_length=win_size)

Just increase the input dimension value and it will work!